# Firebase Firestore rules for read only own data

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm developing a simple app that can upload photos. I'm using firebase firestore and storage. Every time I upload a new photo I create an object like this:

```
struct Item: Codable, Identifiable {
 var id: UUID // photo name
 var uidOwner: String // uid user owner
 var emailOwner: String // email user owner
 var path: String // photo path
 var shared: [String] = []
}
```

I'm running into firestore rules to allow each user to view only the photos they uploaded.

For now the path on firestore is as follows:

[image: Firestore db]

For now I'm just using this rule which only checks that the user is logged in but in the firestorm playground it works and in Xcode I think the resource data uidOwner is null because I haven't access...

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /photos/{photo} {
          allow read: if resource.data.uidOwner == request.auth.uid;
    }
}
```

Could you tell me what rules I should use to allow each user to access only their own data?
Thanks!!

Edit 1:

Here my request on iOS device:

```
func downloadImagesName(){
    self.isLoading = true
    self.itemsPhoto = []
    // Reference
    let imagesCollectionRef = db.collection("photos")

    imagesCollectionRef.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Errore durante il recupero dei documenti: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.isLoading = false
            return
        }
        
        snapshot?.documents.forEach { doc in
            do {
                let item = try doc.data(as: Item.self)
                self.itemsPhoto.append(item)
                
                if doc == snapshot?.documents.last {
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("Errore durante la conversione dei dati: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
        self.isLoading = false
    })
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client query that doesn't work the way you expect, along with the specific data your working with in the app.  We need to be able to see that your query and data matches your rules.  If you're getting a rejection, that means they don't match.  Keep in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not match your rules.  [Rules are not filters.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)

The query is saying that it wants all of the documents in the photos collection, but the rule says that is not allowed.  The rule will not selectively exclude documents from a query.  The rule requires that there is a ["where" filter for equality](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#simple_queries) on the query using the `uidOwner` field as a filter, where the value must only the the user's UID.  You have to add this filter to the query in order for it to work.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding. Are you telling me that I need to add a query like this to my request?

.whereField("uidOwner", uid)

In this case, however, a big doubt arises in my mind: what is the point of putting this query when in theory I should already have the data I need. Let me explain better, when a user is logged in and tries to access that data I think it would be enough to just take the uid of the compared user (from inside request.auth.uid) and compare it with the uidOwner of the Photo object. What am I not understanding?


Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Reading better it seems that I have to do exactly what I wrote above :)

Comment: Code running on web and mobile clients is fundamentally not secure and can't be trusted to do the right thing.  That's why you need rules on the backend to ensure they are not requesting data that the user shouldn't have access to.

Comment: So it is correct that in addition to the rules I have to make a query on mobile to retrieve the correct data

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer is saying. You need a filtered query on the client that matches the requirements of the rules.

Comment: I'm making this query to ensure that the documents are also accessible to users whose email is present in the shared array of the document, however it doesn't work, could you give me some indication on what I'm doing wrong?:
Query:
.whereField("emailOwner", arrayContains: user.email ??"")
Rules:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /photos/{photo} {
     allow read: if request.resource.data.emailOwner in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/photos/$(photo)).data.shared;
     }
   }
}

Comment: If you have new code, please post separately.  Your first issue was addressed, and it's difficult to continue in comments. Please also consider upvoting and accepting this answer as correct with respect to your initial question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I accept this answer and create a new one. I hope you will help me with the other one too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256505/discussion-between-matteog-and-doug-stevenson).